# GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table.Column SEPERATOR ",") returns in reversed order?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT pokemon.ID,
pokemon.internalName,
pokemon.name,
at1.internalName as type1,
mat1.internalName as megaType1,
at2.internalName as type2,
mat2.internalName as megaType2,
pokemon.baseStats,
pokemon.megaBaseStats,
pokemon.genderRate,
pokemon.growthRate,
pokemon.baseEXP,
pokemon.effortPoints,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ab.internalName SEPARATOR ",") AS abilities,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mab.internalName SEPARATOR ",") AS megaAbilities,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT hab.internalName SEPARATOR ",") AS hiddenAbilities,
pokemon.movesByLevelingID,
pokemon.eggMovesID,
egg1.internalName as eggGroup1,
egg2.internalName as eggGroup2,
pokemon.stepsToHatch,
pokemon.height,
pokemon.megaHeight,
pokemon.weight,
pokemon.megaWeight,
colors.name as color,
pokemon.kind,
pokemon.form,
pokemon.pokedex,
pokemon.evolutionsID,
prevo.internalName as prevolution,
megaevo.internalName as megaEvolution,
mgstn.internalName as megaStone

FROM pokemon

LEFT JOIN attackTypes at1
ON pokemon.type1ID=at1.ID

LEFT JOIN attackTypes mat1
ON pokemon.megaType1ID=mat1.ID

LEFT JOIN attackTypes at2
ON pokemon.type2ID=at2.ID

LEFT JOIN attackTypes mat2
ON pokemon.megaType2ID=mat2.ID

LEFT JOIN abilities ab
ON FIND_IN_SET(ab.ID, pokemon.abilitiesID)

LEFT JOIN abilities mab
ON FIND_IN_SET(mab.ID, pokemon.megaAbilitiesID)

LEFT JOIN abilities hab
ON FIND_IN_SET(hab.ID, pokemon.hiddenAbilityID)

LEFT JOIN eggGroups egg1
ON pokemon.eggGroup1ID=egg1.ID

LEFT JOIN eggGroups egg2
ON pokemon.eggGroup2ID=egg2.ID

LEFT JOIN colors
ON pokemon.colorID=colors.ID

LEFT JOIN pokemon prevo
ON pokemon.prevolutionID=prevo.ID

LEFT JOIN pokemon megaevo
ON pokemon.megaEvolutionID=megaevo.ID

LEFT JOIN items mgstn
ON pokemon.megaStoneID=mgstn.ID

WHERE pokemon.internalName = 'CHARIZARD'

GROUP BY pokemon.ID
```

This returns all the data I want except for the columns where I input GROUP_CONCAT, it does pickup the results from the correct table however it displays the information backwards. How do I make it display the first ID it picks up first?

To clarify:

Table:
1 Apple
2 Orange
3 Pear
4 Kiwi
5 Banana

Column:
1,2,4

It would return:
Kiwi,Orange,Apple

Thank you for your time and effort, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to add ORDER BY in GROUP_CONCAT? It allows this

Comment: order by won't work because there is no "order" in the column that it comes from, there's no numerical or alphabetical order. The order that it's in the column is the order and that is being reversed.

Say f.e. in one row the column could say 180,19 and in another row it could be 19,180 and both would be in the right order.

Comment: *"The order that it's in the column is the order"* - table data has no implicit order, and sql is free to order it however it sees fit (which will change depending on the query plan, not the clustered index, or order data was added to the table). If you want data in a particular order you **must** use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If you do know the order, then you are not limited to ordering by the column you are concatenating, e.g. It is still legal SQL to write `GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY ID)`, as demonstrated in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f0d83/2)

Comment: No @GarethD, it's the order in the column that is the order, not the table. "1,2,4" is the order for one pokemon, but for another pokemon it could be 4,1,2 and again another 2,4,1. It's dependent of the game version "X" or "Y" which can't be defined, every first item is Pokemon X, every second item is Pokemon Y and (if) the(re is a) third could be an exception. You can't ORDER BY X because MySQL doesn't know what that is.

The order that it is in the column is the right order and using ORDER BY in any way will not fix that. GROUP_CONCAT reverses the results and I'm asking how to counter that.

Answer (score -1):

`order by` doesn't work inside `group_concat` in Impala since the data is spread across nodes. 
So, use a limit XXX (ensuring it's not lower than the number of rows you have) so that all of the data goes to one data node and then group_concat will work :)

Example:

```
select member, group_concat(event,';') 
from (
    select member, event 
    from table
    order by time 
    limit 10000000000   
     )
group by 1
```